# How to update my site profile?

Tags: support, login

I know this isn't a Ubuntu technical question, though I did register my username through google. Now that I go to update my profile and save it says the email address is already registered. Is there a separate link somewhere im supposed to use to update my profile?

Comment: Most online sites don't allow multiple accounts with the same email, which could be the issue... (Haven't tried it here, but it is the case for many)

Comment: Looks like you have another account on Ask Ubuntu already. Did you lose access to that one?

Comment: yes i did lose access to that one.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to gain access to your old account:

https://askubuntu.com/help/reset-password

Then, you need to merge the old account with the new account:

https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts

Be sure to edit the new account to be "merge keep" and the old one to be "merge delete".